# jquery keeping date picker open all the time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Normal behavior of datepicker is to open when a texbox is clicked and close when a date is selected(clicked). What I need to do is Keep it open from form load and allow user to click repeatedly.I am handling the click event

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can call it on a div instead of an input and it will stay open and be inline.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

You could use it's onSelect event to handle when a date is selected.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the jQuery UI datepicker, use this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

You can then handle the click event and add the selected date to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Corbin 
I would like to provide full example so that help someone in details.

If you want to to have jQueryui calendar default open also capture the click event of calendar follow bellow steps:

HTML Code:

```
  <div id="myDatePicker" class="DateBox datepicker" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></div>
  <input type="hidden" id="dateHidden" name="dateHidden" />
```

and your script should look like bellow:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
      altField: "#dateHidden",
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
     .datepicker("setDate", "0");
 } );
</script>
```

and you can get the selected value of date like bellow code:

```
<script>

   $("#dateHidden").on('input propertychange paste', function(){

      var Loc = $("#Cafe").val();
      var PDate = $("#dateHidden").val();
      //------Functions you call or actions you perform--------//
      //GetLoc(Loc,PDate);

 });

</script>
```