# datetimepicker dissappears upon selection

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker.

```
<input id="all-day-event-date" type="text">
```

It is an input textbox. I trigger it to focus when document loads:

```
$('#all-day-event-date').trigger("focus");
```

And what happens is that I have my input field and my calendar/picker appear, as expected.

```
$("#all-day-event-date").datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,
    onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input) {
        var datetime = $input.val();
        var date = datetime.split(" ")[0];
        $input.val(date);
    }
});
```

It looks like this:

[image]

However, as soon as I select a date, the calendar dissapears:

[image]

How do I make it stay?

This question is different from one asked previously. When I attempt an inline solution:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

What happens is this:

[image]

And it online appears normally when I press the home button:

[image]

This is not the behavior I want. I want the calendar to be there as soon as it loads and never dissapear afterwards, letting user select and reselect without having to click additional boxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery keeping date picker open all the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531867/jquery-keeping-date-picker-open-all-the-time)

Comment: This is an alternative (using a div), not using an input. I tried the div option and it did not work (namely, the behavior of the calendar is then that it only shows up after I click the "home" button of the datetimepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add focusout to remove focus from datepicker input box on selecting date

```
$('#all-day-event-date').focusout();
```

Now, the datepicker should appear again after you focus on the input .

Here is a fiddle that i found very helpful [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7376/%20%22JSFIDDLE)

edit: if you want your datepicker to not disappear at all , read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704548/5410373)

> Use inline calendar with altField

```
<input type="text" id="alternate" size="30" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script>
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      altField: "#alternate"
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I want the calendar to always stay - not only when input is in focus. So, I do not want it to dissappear at all.

Comment: have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28704548/5410373 and this is the simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/menocomp/y2s662b0/1