# jQuery dateTime picker hide click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used [jQuery datetime picker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#onShow) for my website.when I pick a time, it's hide.I want to show it until user click outside.how can I do?

Comment: show us what have you done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery keeping date picker open all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531867/jquery-keeping-date-picker-open-all-the-time)

Comment: see docs: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
closeOnDateSelect: false
closeOnTimeSelect: false
```

Check here:
https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#closeOnDateSelect

Comment: Thank you for your idea.it's direct me to solution. `closeOnTimeSelect:false,` is the solution