# Display a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How can i display a datepicker in a div on document.ready() without onclick of input tag?

```
<div id="return_datepicker"></div>
```

my js -

```
$("#return_datepicker").datepicker();
$("#return_datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
$("#return_datepicker").datepicker('show');
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing? I could show the datepicker with the code you posted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery keeping date picker open all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531867/jquery-keeping-date-picker-open-all-the-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the initialization of datepicker in IIFE.
Try below code -

```
$(function() {
    $("#return_datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#return_datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $("#return_datepicker").datepicker('show');
  });
```

For more detail see [JQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline)